# VB.NET How to access object (deserialized from JSON)

Tags: vb.net

If someone would be so kind as to help me get the highlighted line in to a variable, I would be very grateful.

I tried the following:

```
Dim Fromid = FBrequest.data(0)(3)("from")(2)
```

but it said the key was not present in the array.

Image is at imageshack.us

/img33/1491/wtfjsondeserialized.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing a foreach to see what keys are present in your array. Example:

```
For Each entry As String In FBrequest.data(0)(3)
        Console.WriteLine(entry)
```

Assuming that the "from" is the key that is missing. Additionally, I would also suggestion setting a breakpoint on this line and adding a watch statement. Inspect your `FBRequest.data` variable to see what the contents are.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I believe the data is in an array of key value pairs, of key value pairs. More complex than necessary I think, but I've got it figured out.